# Description for languages that can be solved in time(n)?

Tags: formal-languages, time-complexity

How can one describe all languages that are in
$\mathrm{TIME}(n)$?

It can't be all the regular languages only, as for example $L = \{a^n b^nw \mid w \in \Sigma^* \land n \geq 1\}$ is not regular but in $\mathrm{TIME}(n)$. Furthermore there are regular languages (like any modulo languages) that are not in $\mathrm{TIME}(n)$.

So, is there a nice description for all $L \in \mathrm{TIME}(n)$?

Comment: What do you mean by modulo languages?

Comment: Languages like: $L = \{ w \in \{ a,b\}^* \mid |w|_a + 2\cdot|w|_b \equiv 1 \text{ mod } 7\}$

Comment: @user596542 Well, $\{ w \in \{ a,b\}^* \mid |w|_a + 2\cdot|w|_b \equiv 1 \text{ mod } 7\}$ can be decided in $O(n)$-time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We're not good at characterizing languages that can be decided in deterministic polynomial time. There are multiple characterizations of $\mathrm{NP}$ (e.g., nondeterministic Turing machines, polynomial witnesses, existential second-order logic), but $\mathrm{P}$ seems to be just "stuff you can do in polynomial time on a Turing machine."

Similarly, it's unlikely that there's any alternative characterization of linear time beyond its literal definition.

> Furthermore there are regular languages (like any modulo languages) that are not in $\mathrm{TIME}(n)$.

No there aren't. You can decide any regular language in linear time using a DFA (trivially modify its description so it's a Turing machine).

Comment: Hmm...Thank you for answering :) 
I thought, a TM accepting in $\mathrm{TIME}(n)$ needs to accept a word in $|w| - 1$ steps, so it can use the last step to switch into an $q \in F$. If that would be correct, than you could make it "fall" out of $\mathrm{TIME}(n)$, by making the last letter the reason why the word isn't part of the language...

Comment: @user596542 Ah. Well, if you get hard-line about it, like that, then $\mathrm{TIME}(n)$ contains only the languages $\emptyset$ and $\Sigma^*$, since the machine would have to figure out whether it would accept the empty string in zero steps, which means it must start in either the accepting state or the rejecting state. I guess my answer is really about $\mathrm{TIME}(n+1)$ or $\mathrm{TIME}(O(n))$.